# Ember.js combining two objects from datastore to a string

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I have gathered 1 string from 2 different places in the datastore, an URL and a nickname, what I want to do is combine these two so I can "pre-select" in my dropdown. The problem is, if I check the value within the "declaration of the variables" then I get the text result alerted, but if I alert afterwards when I'm trying to combine the two strings, I get `[Object object], [Object object]` instead. And for some reason I get the Object Objects first, and then the URL and then the nickname, which isn't even the correct order..? The code looks like this:

```
preSelect: function (orgSiteId, orgId) {
    'use strict';
    var url = this.get('store').find('orgSite', orgSiteId).then(function (orgSites) {
        alert(orgSites.get('url'));
        return orgSites.get('url');
    }.bind(this));
    var nickname = this.get('store').find('org', orgId).then(function (orgs) {
        alert(orgs.get('nickname'));
        return orgs.get('nickname');
    }.bind(this));

    this.set('testFillSelect', nickname + ', ' + url);
    alert(this.get('testFillSelect'));
},
```

Is this a situation where I want to use computed properties or observer? I'm new to Ember.js and this feels like it's supposed to be simple.

Comment: You maybe want to read about promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([url, nickname]).then(([urlResult, nicknameResult]) => {
  this.set('testFillSelect', nicknameResult + ', ' + urlResult);
});
```

or just use an async function:

```
async preSelect (orgSiteId, orgId) {
  const orgSite = await this.get('store').find('orgSite', orgSiteId);
  const org = await this.get('store').find('org', orgId);

  const url = orgSite.get('url');
  const nickname = org.get('nickname');

  this.set('testFillSelect', nickname + ', ' + url);
}
```

Comment: I would personally use the async approach, but it looks like the OP is using the legacy object syntax. So I'd recommend using with ember-concurrency:

preSelect: task(function*() {})

Comment: agree. async *does* work with legacy object syntax tho. The question is which babel version is used.

Comment: There is a huge performance difference between using or not using `Promise.all` in this case. It will either do the requests in parallel or one after each other. You could use `async`/`await` syntax together with `Promise.all`: `await Promise.all([])`

Comment: @Lux Thank you good sir, worked like a charm.. I was really stuck on that one :)